# How can I open a .dmg file?

Tags: files, file-format, archive

I've got a [.dmg](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image) file, and I can't figure out how to open it. How can I open it?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Install [dmg2img](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dmg2img).

Next, read the [package information page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/amd64/dmg2img) and the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/dmg2img.1.html) to see if it is useful to you.

The application seems to convert .dmg to a file that can be mounted using the `mount` command:

```
dmg2img file.dmg imagefile.img
```

From your [Wikipedia article](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image), the next command seems to be available to do that:

```
sudo mount -o loop -t hfsplus imagefile.img /mnt
```

In this way, the file `imagefile.img` is a result from `dmg2iso` and the contents will be available at `/mnt`. If the hfsplus type is not detected, you might need to load the kernel module for it:

```
sudo modprobe hfsplus
```

When done, you can unmount it by running:

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

Comment: This will not work if the dmg file has 10.6+ compressed files in it.

Comment: I get this error - `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0`

Comment: @tuxdna Do you really have a HFS image? Check the output of `file file.dmg`. You can also try `7z l file.dmg` to list the contents.

Comment: I am using `dmg2img v1.6.2`. I ran dmg2img on `mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg` which created `mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64.img`, but it doesn't mount.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Thanks! Now it works. Check my answer below.

Comment: I'm getting segmentation faults when trying to use a multipart DMG.

Comment: For future readers, @SkylarIttner reported the issue here: https://github.com/Lekensteyn/dmg2img/issues/7

Comment: This utility does not support password protected .dmg files

Answer (score 76):

To extract it, it is much easier to use 7zip:

```
7z x file.dmg
```

Comment: Thanks, `7z` did the job, whereas `dmg2img` complained about a corrupted dmg image.

Comment: Note that 7z works only for unencrypted dmg images

Comment: This just created a file called `0.unknown partition` for me.

Answer (score 33):

This works for me:

- Extract using `7z x`
- Locate the `hfs` partition file
- Mount it to a directory

Extract using `7z x`

```
root # aptitude install p7zip-full
root # 7z x ../mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg 

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_IN,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Processing archive: ../mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg

Extracting  0.MBR
Extracting  1.Primary GPT Header
Extracting  2.Primary GPT Table
Extracting  3.free
Extracting  4.hfs
Extracting  5.free
Extracting  6.Backup GPT Table
Extracting  7.Backup GPT Header

Everything is Ok

Files: 8
Size:       125475840
Compressed: 117543935
root # ls
0.MBR  1.Primary GPT Header  2.Primary GPT Table  3.free  4.hfs  5.free  6.Backup GPT Table  7.Backup GPT Header
```

Locate the `hfs` partition ( here it is `4.hfs` file ):

```
root # ls -l
total 122548
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       512 Feb  5 16:06 0.MBR
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       512 Feb  5 16:06 1.Primary GPT Header
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     16384 Feb  5 16:06 2.Primary GPT Table
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      3072 Feb  5 16:06 3.free
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 125435904 Feb  5 16:06 4.hfs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      2560 Feb  5 16:06 5.free
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     16384 Feb  5 16:06 6.Backup GPT Table
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       512 Feb  5 16:06 7.Backup GPT Header
```

Mount it to folder:

```
root # mkdir t
root # mount -oloop 4.hfs t
root # cd t/
root # ls
mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg  MySQL.prefPane  MySQLStartupItem.pkg  ReadMe.txt
```

Comment: You can specify the single file you want to extract: `7z x ../mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg 4.hfs`

Answer (score 8):

If you succeed with the instructions from Lekensteyn and binfalse more power to you.  If you are getting

```
$ lsmod | grep hfs
hfs                    54782  0 
hfsplus                84912  0
$ sudo mount -o loop,ro -t hfsplus imagefile.img /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
```

Right now Ubuntu only comes with dmg2img version 1.6.2 and version 1.6.4 sometimes makes a difference.  Also you can extract specific partitions from a dmg and only some of them are hfs+

```
$ dmg2img -l file.dmg
partition 0: Protective Master Boot Record (MBR : 0)
partition 1: GPT Header (Primary GPT Header : 1)
partition 2: GPT Partition Data (Primary GPT Table : 2)
partition 3:  (Apple_Free : 3)
partition 4: disk image (Apple_HFS : 4)
partition 5:  (Apple_Free : 5)
partition 6: GPT Partition Data (Backup GPT Table : 6)
partition 7: GPT Header (Backup GPT Header : 7)
$ dmg2img -p 4 file.dmg imagefile.img
```

- Current Ubuntu versions come with 1.6.5 as of version 14.04

Answer (score 4):

When using `dmg2img file.dmg imagefile.img` on linux if you get 
ERROR: Inflation failed message, just install **7zip** as

```
sudo aptitude install p7zip-full
```

and issue the following command on terminal

```
7z x your_file.dmg
```

- find the InstallMacOSX.pkg/InstallESD.dmg
- issue the command `dmg2img InstallESD.dmg imagefile.img` on the terminal.

Now you can mount imagefile.img with

```
modprobe hfsplus
```

and then

```
mount -t hfsplus -o loop mountain.img /mnt
```

Answer (score 4):

In the case of some `.dmg`s, you can neither `7z x` them, nor `mount` the result of `dmg2img`.

In that case, the `.img` resulting from `dmg2img your.dmg new.img` can have its paritions extracted with `7z x`:

```
$ 7z x factor-macosx-x86-64-0.98.dmg
[...]
Extracting archive: factor-macosx-x86-64-0.98.dmg
ERROR: factor-macosx-x86-64-0.98.dmg
factor-macosx-x86-64-0.98.dmg
Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [Dmg] archive

$ dmg2img factor-macosx-x86-64-0.98.dmg factor.img
[...]
factor-macosx-x86-64-0.98.dmg --> factor.img
[...]
Archive successfully decompressed as factor.img

$ sudo mount -o loop -t hfsplus factor.img /mnt
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop5, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

$ 7z x factor.img 

[...]
Extracting archive: factor.img
[...]
Everything is Ok                                

Folders: 2717
Files: 10266
Size:       176431113
Compressed: 264214528

$ ls -lah factor factor/factor/
factor:
total 24K
drwx------  6 cat cat 4.0K Jul 30  2018  .
drwxr-xr-x 21 cat cat 4.0K Feb 19 16:28  ..
drwx------  8 cat cat 4.0K Jul 30  2018  factor
drwx------  2 cat cat 4.0K Jul 30  2018 '[HFS+ Private Data]'
drwx------  2 cat cat 4.0K Jul 30  2018 '.HFS+ Private Directory Data'$'\r'
drwx------  2 cat cat 4.0K Jul 30  2018  .Trashes

factor/factor/:
total 97M
drwx------   8 cat cat 4.0K Jul 30  2018 .
drwx------   6 cat cat 4.0K Jul 30  2018 ..
drwx------ 163 cat cat 4.0K Jul 30  2018 basis
drwx------  45 cat cat 4.0K Jul 30  2018 core
-rw-r--r--   1 cat cat  702 Jul 30  2018 .dir-locals.el
drwx------ 288 cat cat  12K Jul 30  2018 extra
-rw-r--r--   1 cat cat   32 Jul 30  2018 factor
drwx------   3 cat cat 4.0K Jul 30  2018 Factor.app
-rw-r--r--   1 cat cat  97M Jul 30  2018 factor.image
-rw-r--r--   1 cat cat   40 Jul 30  2018 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--   1 cat cat   43 Jul 30  2018 git-id
-rw-r--r--   1 cat cat 366K Jul 30  2018 libfactor.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 cat cat  16K Jul 30  2018 libfactor-ffi-test.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 cat cat 1.3K Jul 30  2018 LICENSE.txt
drwx------   9 cat cat 4.0K Jul 30  2018 misc
-rw-r--r--   1 cat cat 4.6K Jul 30  2018 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 cat cat 3.6K Jul 30  2018 .travis.yml
drwx------   2 cat cat 4.0K Jul 30  2018 work
```

Success!

Comment: Multiple answers suggest directly using `7z` on the dmg file. Why convert it then?

Comment: @Olorin this is for when `7z x your.dmg` fails with `Can't open as archive: 1`, and when `dmg2img`'s output won't be accepted by `mount` either. I'll clarify

Comment: I was facing same problem but this answer helped my situation.

Answer (score 3):

First of all install [DMG2IMG](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DMG2IMG). Now you can convert it to `IMG`:

```
dmg2img your.dmg new.img
```

The `IMG` can be mounted with:

```
sudo modprobe hfsplus
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o loop new.img /mnt
```

And take a look at `/mnt`

Answer (score 1):

following the answer of @aman and @tuxdna, because dmg2img doesn't seem to work on compressed dmg images.

so i made a bash script (tested on ubuntu 14.10) to automatize the process of :

- extracting with 7z in a temp folder
- looking for which partition to mount
- copy the hfs/hfsplus folder/partition somewhere else
- delete the temp folder
- mount the partition

find it here: https://github.com/aurelien-rainone/scripts/blob/master/mountdmg.sh

example of use:

```
panty@Computerino:[~/scripts]: mountdmg.sh -t hfsplus -d /mnt ~/Downloads/cutecom-ng.dmg 

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)

Processing archive: /home/panty/Downloads/cutecom-ng.dmg

Extracting  0.MBR
Extracting  1.Primary GPT Header
Extracting  2.Primary GPT Table
Extracting  3.free
Extracting  4.hfs
Extracting  5.free
Extracting  6.Backup GPT Table
Extracting  7.Backup GPT Header

Everything is Ok

Files: 8
Size:       33549312
Compressed: 10059312
mountdmg.sh: successfully mounted 4.hfs on /dev/loop0
mountdmg.sh: run sudo umount /dev/loop0 when finished
```

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in some of the posts to this topic only work on older versions of 7z.

If you want to extract JUST the 4.hfs file from a .dmg file (i.e: just one level deep) and are using a newer version of 7-zip then you need to use different parameters:

In 7-Zip [64] 9.20 you can use this command:

```
7z x file.dmg 4.hfs
```

In 7-Zip [64] 16.02 you need to use this command:

```
7z x -t* file.dmg 4.hfs
```