# Is there a program similar to Wine that runs Mac software?

Tags: software-recommendation, wine, virtualization, mac, playonlinux

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04, and I have got a Mac program in the Mac installation format (I believe it to a `.dmg`) which I wish to use, however I don't really have a functioning Mac to use it on and would prefer to use Ubuntu, so is there a similar program to Wine and PoL which runs Mac programs as opposed to, or as well as, Mac programs?

Comment: Please update your question as to what program you want to run.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/38112/how-can-i-open-a-dmg-file

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: It's a chess app you wouldn't probably know of, however I would like the answer to be less program specific and more general so that it will help others in future, and me in future too so that I don't have to keep asking new questions about new programs...

Comment: See my answer coming soon...

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Also, I am not fully sure that it is a `.dmg` as there was a naming issue...

Comment: mounting the `.dmg` wouldn't help you run the software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there currently aren't any WINE like emulators that run Mac applications. However there is an application which is meant to do this which is currently in development called "[Darling](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/08/os-x-apps-run-on-linux-with-wine-like-emulator-for-mac-software/)".

Comment: If it's graphical, Darling probably can't handle it at the moment, see: [http://www.darlinghq.org/project-status]