# Open encrypted .dmg file?

Tags: files, encryption, archive, file-format

I have an old encrypted .dmg file I would like to open. Tried what I could but now I am out of options.

**Option 1: [dmg2img](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/dmg2img.1.html)**
Getting error message: `dmg image is corrupted`

Then I tried to use [vfdecrypt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/vfdecrypt.1.html), but got the error `(2) during key unwrap operation!`

**Option 2: [libfvde](https://github.com/libyal/libfvde)**
Error during the mmls command: `Cannot determine partition type`

**Option 3: [HFSExplorer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/catacombae/files/HFSExplorer/0.23.1/)**
Error during execution:

```
Trying to detect CEncryptedEncoding structure...
CEncryptedEncoding structure found! Creating filter stream...
Detecting sparseimage structure...
Trying to detect UDIF structure...
UDIF structure found! Creating filter stream...
Could not open file! Exception thrown:
org.catacombae.dmgextractor.DmgException: Invalid zlib data!
```

I read [How can I open a .dmg file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38112/how-can-i-open-a-dmg-file) and followed most of the tips and tricks, but I am stuck here.